# Getting Error in XML testng file while running the test case in a suite

Tags: java, maven, selenium, pom.xml, testng.xml

I am trying to run a testng xml file in a suite.But when i run file
as run as testng suite i am getting below error in console

```
org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 37; columnNumber: 9; The content of element type "suite" must match "(groups?,(listeners|packages|test|parameter|method-selectors|suite-files)*)".
at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:327)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:348)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:995)
at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12.initialize(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:22)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:97)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 37; columnNumber: 9; The content of element type "suite" must match "(groups?,(listeners|packages|test|parameter|method-selectors|suite-files)*)".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1994)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:879)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1783)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2970)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:38)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:152)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:233)
    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:295)
    ... 6 more

Since i am new to automation testing i am not able to find out why is the issue arises.I checked with all syntax error and i feel that it
is correct.But i am not able to solve this issue.This is my xml file which i am trying to run but getting error

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="Merck Production Smoke Test Automation Test Suite">
    <parameter name="appURL" value="https://webqws.sial.com"/>
    <parameter name="browserType" value="chrome"/>   
    <listeners>
    <listener class-name="customListener.TestNGCustomReportListener"> 
    </listener>
    <listener class-name="customListener.Customreporter"/>
    </listeners>
    <!--  --> <test name="Merck Production Suite - Automation Scripts 
    Execution - US">
    <parameter name="countryName" value="United States"/>      
    <classes>
    <class name="testScript.Merck_Web_eCommerce_SmokeTest"/>   
    </classes>    
    </test> -->    
    <test name="Merck Production Suite - Automation Scripts Execution - UK">    
    <parameter name="countryName" value="United Kingdom"/>    
    <classes>    
    <class name="testScript.Merck_Web_eCommerce_SmokeTest"/>    
    </classes>     
    </test>    
    <!-- <test name="Merck Production Suite - Automation Scripts Execution - 
   INDIA">
   <parameter name="countryName" value="India"/>   
   <classes>
   <class name="testScript.Merck_Web_eCommerce_SmokeTest"/>
   </classes>   
   </test>  -->    
   </suite>
```

Comment: Add your xml file to the question

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  Can you validate your test xml file (in eclipse, ...)? (When you pasted it literally),I am suspicious about the unmatched closing `-->` (after first closing `</test>`)

Comment: Ok..let me check

Comment: Thank you for your response.I have validate the XML file in eclipse and i got error like "The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well  formed"  I am not getting still for which line i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

(most probable) Problem reasons:

1. Unmatched closing `-->` in your xml file.

   Solution: Delete it.
2. (After fixing 1., I still had:) "invalid DTD"(!), like [here](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1385).

   Solution: Use http**s**!;) (in `<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >`)

Comment: and i got below error"org.testng.TestNGException: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: I got a similar exception(org.xml.sax.SAXParseException) where in my case "dtb" url was being used with "http" rather than "https". Just changing that made it work.